# Why the elasticsearch highlight did not work?

Tags: django, elasticsearch

I try to highlight the result of my searching using elasticsearch. Unfortunately, somehow it did not work.

This is my code:

```
def page_results(request, page_id):
s = Search(using=Elasticsearch())
keyword = request.GET.get('q')
if keyword:
    posts = s[start:end].query(
        "multi_match",
        query=keyword,
        fields=['head_title^4', 'description^3','url^5', 'description.ngram'],
    )
    posts = posts.highlight('description')
```